# Cannot find Transaction. If the transaction is deferred, it has already been executed or expired

Tags: transactions, deferred-transactions

I deployed a smart contract on the local blockchain. After that, I executed on the transaction in which I passed 1000 hex strings as parameters which are to be get saved in the table. It returns me the transaction receipt. I copy the transaction id and search on https://local.bloks.io/, it displays:

```
Cannot find Transaction 1f27fae28ac77f084e258594a85563c1cdc91a18f816bb729d6b5685cd8f5d19
If the transaction is deferred, it has already been executed or expired.
```

Whereas, the data is saved in the respective table. I read about the deferred transaction if the transaction takes execution time more than `30ms` this happens. I am not getting anything. If the transaction is not executed then how the data gets saved in the table? And how to resolve this deferred transaction issue? Please help.

Comment: Did you activate `eosio::history_api_plugin`?

Comment: yes. For the rest of the transactions, I can find the transaction. This is only for the one who is taking more than 30 ms to execute.